# I am not getting the user location on maps

Tags: java, android

```java
    private static final String TAG = "LocationUpdateService";
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        // Setting up the  location request with a shorter interval and distance
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000); // 1 second
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(500); // 0.5 seconds
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(5 f); // 5 meters

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                for (Location location: locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Location Updated: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
                    // Handle the updated location here

                    // Since I an Using the BroadcastReceiver that's why I don't need to handel it here
                }
            }
        };

        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (fusedLocationClient != null && locationCallback != null) {
            fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        }
    }
```

This is my code and I am using the broadcast receiver also and on the maps activity I want to show the location of the user when the user is moving from one place to another.

I have tried many solutions but they are not working.

Comment: Ok.  First off, you're not asking for runtime location permission.  That's required.  Secondly, if you're using Google maps you wouldn't use FusedLocationProvider directly, you'd use the map's location functionality.  Third-  you aren't setting the location to the map, so even if you wanted to do things the hard way you aren't actually trying to do that.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location#my-location for how to use map's built in location functionality

Comment: The broadcast receiver is not the best choice for this. You need to create a background service to get the constants location of the user. For this you need to call the location request contantly by using Looper which you passed null